# inner join between 2 tables - odd syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

see the following SQL..

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.id, tables3 t3
WHERE t3.id = 999
```

what kind of join is there here? between t1 and t3?. I mean what is the comma all about?

Answer (score 4):

A `,` in the `FROM` clause is a deprecated shorthand for `CROSS JOIN`

A better way to write the query is with an explicit `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.user_id = t2.id CROSS JOIN
     tables3 t3
WHERE t3.id = 999 ;
```

As written, the query makes no sense.  Assuming that `t3.id = 999` is true and appears once, then this is equivalent to:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.user_id = t2.id;
```

If the value doesn't exist, then no rows will be returned.

Comment: Could also use an `INNER JOIN tables3 t3 ON t3.id == 999`

Comment: _what kind of join is there here? between t1 and t3?. I mean what is the comma all about?_

Comment: The comma is deprecated syntax meaning cross join

Comment: @Caleth thanks. now that i understand the this is a cross join it makes perfectly sense that this query does not make sense. the person that wrote this query, did not intend it i think

Comment: Not deprecated, only old fashioned.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.id
JOIN tables3 t3 ON t2.id=t3.id
WHERE t3.id = 999
```

Comment: This gives different results to the original query, and has no explanation

Comment: @Caleth can you explain me how it gives different result set

Comment: t3.id has no relation with any of the ids in table1 and table2

Comment: This is not the same query at all and it doesn't answer the question.